# Flutter does not work after installation on windows 10

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried installing flutter by downloading the package. After extracting the package, and adding flutter bin path to my environmental variables, I couldn't get flutter to work.
I tried `flutter doctor`, there was no output, message, or error. There was just a popup window that flashes and closed immediately so I wasn't able to view the content.
I don't have any log to show because I didn't get any at all.

Tried adding C:\WINDOWS\system32 to windows path and I even deleted my existing dart sdk.

I expected flutter doctor to give output about what what went wrong but it's all blank.

Comment: I"ve been able to solve this
I was able to solve it, by clearing the cache folder in flutter/bin.

Answer (score 1):

I"ve been able to solve this
I was able to solve it, by clearing the cache folder in flutter/bin.